# How to change Laravel url to localhost/website to get assets?

Tags: php, laravel

I transferred all the files in my laravel website to a folder called "project" except the public folder. I put all the files from the public folder to the main folder so I won't have to use "php artisan serve" every time I use the website locally like for example `192.168.1.100/website`. The problem is that the assets and links became `192.168.1.100/dashboard`, what I need is that `192.168.1.100/website/dashboard`

Comment: why not use laravel valet, this is a much better solution, Other than that, create some htaccess or nginx configs depending on your server for rewrites.

Comment: @MichaelMano never heard of laravel valet before

Comment: what os are you on. if you are using mac, valet is a development environment, it comes with nginx all configured, dnsmasq to set a `.test` tld which you can link to a folder. so `anything.test` will go to 127.0.0.1 and to a folder `~/sites/test` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/valet

Comment: @MichaelMano Im using ubuntu. I'll check valet now. I hope this is easy to adjust for local network website